# Expressjs modifying req.params in express.Router

Tags: node.js, express

According to the documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)
I am supposed to be able to modify the request object. Here is an example of what is not working for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.params.time = Date.now();
  next();
});
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Time: ', req.params.time);
  res.send('Something out');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Ideas on how to do this? (node v6.4.0, npm 3.10.3, express 4.14.0)

Answer (score 2):

I'll make an educated guess and say that Express repopulates the req.params object with the request GET parameters. Instead, do something like this:

```
req.time = Date.now();

// snip

console.log(`Time: ${req.time}`);
```

Comment: That's it! Man, that was simple. Thanks.

Comment: I think that `req.locals` to store request vars/method and `app.locals` to stote global application vars/method is better.

Answer (score 1):

Params is only available if the route definition has params - which is not the case in your example.

Normally you use params this way:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

So adding a param `time` would allow you to modify it.
But I think this is not what you want - because you have to change the URL. So better use something like

```
req.somevariable = variable;
```

to pass it to the next middleware with next();

Comment: This answer is more correct than mine. Please accept this one and not mine.